# Getting invalid datatype error while creating table regestration

Tags: oracle10g

```
CREATE TABLE regestration 
  ( 
     email     VARCHAR(30), 
     PASSWORD  VARCHAR(15), 
     f_name    VARCHAR(25), 
     contactno VARCHAR(10), 
     address   VARCHAR(30), 
     city      VARCHAR(15), 
     country   VARCHAR(20), 
     gen       VARCHAR(15), 
     ac_type   VARCHAR(20), 
     e-bank    VARCHAR(15), 
     status    VARCHAR(10) 
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

The [object naming rules](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm) include:

> Nonquoted identifiers can contain only alphanumeric characters from
>   your database character set and the underscore (_), dollar sign ($),
>   and pound sign (#). Database links can also contain periods (.) and
>   "at" signs (@). Oracle strongly discourages you from using $ and # in
>   nonquoted identifiers.
>
> Quoted identifiers can contain any characters and punctuations marks
>   as well as spaces. However, neither quoted nor nonquoted identifiers
>   can contain double quotation marks or the null character (\0).

You are trying to create a nonquoted identifier as `e-bank`. That is not a valid name; the hyphen/dash punctuation mark is not allowed in a nonquoted identifier. While you could quote it it will only cause you problems later, anyone who has to refer to the column will struggle (and possibly curse you for making their lives harder), and based on the other column names you probably meant to use an underscore anyway:

```
CREATE TABLE regestration 
  ( 
     email     VARCHAR(30), 
     PASSWORD  VARCHAR(15), 
     f_name    VARCHAR(25), 
     contactno VARCHAR(10), 
     address   VARCHAR(30), 
     city      VARCHAR(15), 
     country   VARCHAR(20), 
     gen       VARCHAR(15), 
     ac_type   VARCHAR(20), 
     e_bank    VARCHAR(15), 
     status    VARCHAR(10) 
  );

Table REGESTRATION created.
```